# Ratio test, limit for a certain problem

Tags: limits

Right now I'm the determine to radius of convergence of a given power series, I think I'm doing it right but I cannot understand how the limit for

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$

becomes $1/e$, is there anyone who got a method of showing me that this is actually real. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Take( ln) assume limit= L
  ln (L)= lim  n ln (n÷(n+1))
                                            [ Dividing inside bracket by n]
            =(ln (1÷(1+(1÷n))))÷(1÷n)    [(  1÷n) =t ] take substitution 
               =[ln1- ln (1+t)]/  t   (ln1=0 )
 =>  ln (1+t )÷t =1 by 0÷0 form as t  tends to zero value is 1
      lnL=-1
        L=e^(-1) 
L= 1÷e

Comment: Shiva, the idea seems good, but you have to format it better as it is now almost unreadable. You have good tutorials to use Latex. Improve it or almost for sure the answer will end flagged or deleted.